Install of a custom package failing
I am creating a CLI package. I'm publishing to a GitHub account, and I have the .npmrc pointing to the @myorg:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com. I can see the contents of the published package with npm pack <package>, but when I try to npm install <package>, the operation fails because it can't find the package.json. This is because the package folder is not created in node_modules.
I ran an npm install --verbose <package> and all of the requests seem to succeed preceding the error.
This is the second package I have created and the first one works just fine.
Why might the package folder not be created?
This is what my package.json looks like in the package being published.
{
  "name": "@myorg/cy-membership-test-client",
  "bin": {
    "cy-membership-test-client": "./lib/index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "patch-release": "npm version patch && npm publish && git push --follow-tags"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/myorg/cy-membership-test-client.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
  },
  "owner": "myorg",
  "author": "Josh Russo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/myorg/cy-membership-test-client/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/myorg/cy-membership-test-client#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@myorg/cy-membership-api-client": "^1.0.104",
    "@myorg/cy-membership-test-client": "file:",
    "command-line-args": "^6.0.0",
    "cy-membership-test-client": "file:",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.3.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.3"
}

This is what the verbose output looks like.
npm verb cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\jrusso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm info using npm@9.2.0
npm info using node@v20.10.0
npm verb title npm install @myorg/cy-membership-test-client
npm verb argv "install" "--loglevel" "verbose" "@myorg/cy-membership-test-client"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\jrusso\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-16T19_08_22_238Z-
npm verb logfile C:\Users\jrusso\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-16T19_08_22_238Z-debug-0.log
npm verb shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json missing from node_modules: node_modules/membership-test-client-install-test
npm http fetch GET 200 https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myorg%2fcy-membership-test-client 456ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-node 165ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/command-line-args 217ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@swc%2fcore 111ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@swc%2fhelpers 90ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@swc%2fwasm 100ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode 83ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 77ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typical 112ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-back 118ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/undici-types 151ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/find-replace 181ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/arg 181ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-require 187ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@cspotcode%2fsource-map-support 199ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@tsconfig%2fnode16 214ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/make-error 241ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-compile-cache-lib 240ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@tsconfig%2fnode14 244ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn 248ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.camelcase 271ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn-walk 271ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff 273ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yn 284ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@tsconfig%2fnode10 313ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@tsconfig%2fnode12 329ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@jridgewell%2ftrace-mapping 100ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@jridgewell%2fresolve-uri 113ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@jridgewell%2fsourcemap-codec 118ms (cache revalidated)
npm verb stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\my-org\membership-test-client-install-test\node_modules\@myorg\cy-membership-test-client\package.json'
npm verb cwd C:\temp\my-org\membership-test-client-install-test
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm verb node v20.10.0
npm verb npm  v9.2.0
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\temp\my-org\membership-test-client-install-test\node_modules\@myorg\cy-membership-test-client/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\my-org\membership-test-client-install-test\node_modules\@myorg\cy-membership-test-client\package.json'    
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm verb exit -4058
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1726513702302
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1726513702303
npm verb code -4058

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jrusso\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-16T19_08_22_238Z-debug-0.log

This is what the npm pack output looks like.
npm notice
npm notice   @myorg/cy-membership-test-client@0.0.4
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 0B     .env
npm notice 23B    build.ps1
npm notice 2.8kB  lib/index.js
npm notice 77B    lib/messageTest.js
npm notice 6.2kB  lib/userTests.js
npm notice 725B   package.json
npm notice 80B    run.ps1
npm notice 1.6kB  src/index.ts
npm notice 193B   src/messageTest.ts
npm notice 5.0kB  src/userTests.ts
npm notice 12.3kB tsconfig.json
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          @myorg/cy-membership-test-client
npm notice version:       0.0.4
npm notice filename:      myorg-cy-membership-test-client-0.0.4.tgz
npm notice package size:  7.3 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 29.0 kB
npm notice shasum:        2ef3f1a94b93c8ca347433cc317d3c6dd3ba97e7
npm notice integrity:     sha512-wbq6+NtXgZVfK[...]XCDQIWjy5N6mA==
npm notice total files:   11
npm notice
myorg-cy-membership-test-client-0.0.4.tgz


Update 2024-09-17
I ran SysInternals Process Monitor to view the file system behavior when installing my existing package and this package. I can clearly see Node creating the node_modules folders with the existing package. With this package none of the folders are even attempted to be created.

I found the problem. I had a dependency entry of "cy-membership-test-client": "file:", that I had created when I was initially debugging the "bin" symlink functionality.
I removed that and everything works perfectly.

In the project you trying to install make sure you have a package.json;
If you have a package-lock.json then delete it and try again.

Note the npm pack output at the end. It has a package.json and no package-lock.json. The real problem is that it seems like none of the files are being either downloaded properly or maybe extracted properly.

"In the project you trying to install" not the one being deployed; Can you run $ ls in the root of the project you trying to install the one being published?

This is the first and only install in the new project. I ran npm init, then created the .npmrc, and then tried to run npm install <package>

looks like a complex debugging; maybe try to copy the other project you mentioned and just change what you need; maybe try to install in a linux machine; clear cache; reinstall node.... good luck
